# Add boxplots in the coplot() function

Tags: r

Consider the dataset "ToothGrow" from the "datasets" package: a 60 rows dataset for three variables: "Tooth length", "Supplement lenght", "Dose in milligrams per day".

```
str(ToothGrowth)

## 'data.frame':    60 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ len : num  4.2 11.5 7.3 5.8 6.4 10 11.2 11.2 5.2 7 ...
##  $ supp: Factor w/ 2 levels "OJ","VC": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
##  $ dose: num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
```

I use the function `coplot()` to see the effect of the variable `dose` on the variable `len` for each factor of `supp`.

```
with(ToothGrowth, coplot(len ~ dose | supp))
```

[image]

How can I create the same plot with boxplots for `len ~ dose`, instead of having a point for each case?

Using the `coplot()` function from R base graphics would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(lattice)
data("ToothGrowth")
ToothGrowth[,3]<-factor(ToothGrowth[,3])
#before
xyplot(len ~ dose | supp, data=ToothGrowth, layout=c(2,1))
#after
bwplot(len ~ dose | supp, data=ToothGrowth, layout=c(2,1))
```

The result is the following:

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want to only employ the R base package you can use the following.

```
coplot(len ~ dose | supp,  data=ToothGrowth, xlim = c(0, 4),
   panel = function(x, y, ...){boxplot(y ~ x, add=TRUE)})
```

Which yields:

[image]

Comment: Your solution is interesting. Do you know how could I adapt it to the graphics base package and the `coplot()` function?

Comment: @Worice, why/what do you want to use coplot() for? What you are seeing *is* a coplot, just that bwplot takes care of it by providing the aes definition "len ~ dose **| supp**" where "|" can be understood as by. I'm also not sure what you mean by "graphics base package".

Comment: R has its own graphics functions. Packages like ggplot2 and lattice provide more powerful/practical functions. Your answer is correct, but I am also curious to know if there is a way to solve the problem with the base package.

Comment: @Worice, since your curiosity wasn't expressed in the original question I chose the, in my opinion, most flexible alternative. To do this using only the base R-package you can use the panel argument of coplot. I've edited my answer. Don't forget to mark this question as answered.